# Using gdal_merge to create a grayscale mosaic

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, mosaic, ecw

My gdal fu is weak and I need help! ;)

I'm creating a mosaic in geotiff from hundreds of ecw. I created a list of all my rasters and used this command:

```
gdal_merge -o c:\temp\output_image.tif -q -v --optfile c:\temp\rasterlist.txt
```

It's working, but I'd like now to create one with only the red band. Is it possible to do it with gdal_merge?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to take the merged raster you have just made and save out the red band (perhaps using [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) and the -b switch).  Alternatively you could use QGIS' raster calculator to save only the red band as a new raster.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the `output_image.tif` yet, you can follow the advice of @MappaGnosis, i.e.:

```
gdal_translate -b 1 output_image.tif output_red.tif
```

Alternatively, it's possible to extract the red band while building a `VRT` mosaic with [gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) and then translate from `VRT` to `GTIFF` format:

```
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list c:\temp\rasterlist.txt -b 1 output_red.vrt
gdal_translate output_red.vrt output_red.tif
```

The two main advantages are that it's required less space on disk (`VRT` are simply `XML` files) and the process is faster than creating the mosaic with all the bands.

Answer (score 2):

It's highly inefficient to merge mosaic using gdal merge.

Instead, make a VRT (Virtual Dataset) and convert it to your favourite format.